# A homework problem on series(AGP series)

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm stuck with this problem and have no clue how the answer is like this.
The problem asks me to find out the value of $(2^\frac{1}{4}.4^\frac{1}{8}.8^\frac{1}{16}......\infty)$ . The answer should be $\frac{3}{2}$. 
I've proceeded this way:[image]

I've no idea how the answer is $\frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: The $\infty$ is extraneous and superfluous and misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $a_n = \left( 2^n \right)^{1/2^{n+1}} = 2^{n2^{-n-1}}$.

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
S &=& \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac n{2^n} \\
\dfrac12 S &=& \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac n{2^{n+1}} \\
&=& \displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac {n-1}{2^n} \\
S - \dfrac12 S &=& \displaystyle \dfrac1{2^1} + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac {n-(n-1)}{2^n} \\
&=& \displaystyle \dfrac12 + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac 1{2^n} \\
&=& \displaystyle \dfrac12 + \dfrac12 \\
&=& \displaystyle 1 \\
\dfrac12 S &=& 1 \\
S &=& 2 \\
\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac n{2^n} &=& 2 \\
\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac n{2^{n+1}} &=& 1 \\
\displaystyle \prod_{n=1}^\infty 2^{\frac n{2^{n+1}}} &=& 2 \\
\end{array}$$

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=prod_%28n%3D1%29%5Einfty+%282%5En%29%5E%281%2F2%5E%28n%2B1%29%29) agrees with my answer.